# how can i limit the options in a dropdownlist to only valid options?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

allow me to further explain, i have a lot of people in my db. and they have a one to many option to have an action plan, my page displays all of the people that have action plans. i also have dropdownlist to filter threw all of the people that have action plans... this works fine. the dropdownlists work fine, the part i cannot get is that there is a dropdownlist filter with the persons name(to find all of the action plans for that one person), but the dropdownlist shows ALL the names in the db and not just the ones that have action plans, is there any way to limit the dropdownlist to only show people that HAVE action plans?

sorry if there is already a post on this... i have been looking and looking but cannot find the solution

thanks

p.s. this might help.... and yes i am using MVC
this is in my view

```
<td><%=Html.DropDownList("FORMER_BORROWER", "All")%></td>
        <td><%=Html.DropDownList("CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY", "All")%></td>
        <td><%=Html.DropDownList("RESPONSIBLE_PARTY", "All")%></td>
        <td><%=Html.DropDownList("COMPLETED", "All")%></td>
        <td><%=Html.DropDownList("TARGET_DATE", "All")%></td>
```

this is in my controller

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<ACTION_PLAN>();
    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.COMPLETED != null);

    // former borrower
    if ((Request.Form["FORMER_BORROWER"] != null) && Request.Form["FORMER_BORROWER"] != "")
    {
        FormerBorrower = Request.Form["FORMER_BORROWER"];
        ViewData["FORMER_BORROWER"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.Loans where (n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME != null) select new { n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME, FORMER_BORROWER_NAMEID = n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME }).Distinct().ToList(), "FORMER_BORROWER_NAMEID", "FORMER_BORROWER_NAME", FormerBorrower);
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Loan.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME == FormerBorrower);
    }
    else
    {
        FormerBorrower = "";
        ViewData["FORMER_BORROWER"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.Loans where (n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME != null) select new { n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME, FORMER_BORROWER_NAMEID = n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME }).Distinct().ToList(), "FORMER_BORROWER_NAMEID", "FORMER_BORROWER_NAME");
    }

    // current ownership entity
    if ((Request.Form["CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY"] != null) && Request.Form["CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY"] != "")
    {
        CurrentOwnershipEntity = Request.Form["CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY"];
        ViewData["CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.DOM_CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITies select n).ToList(), "CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY", "CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY", CurrentOwnershipEntity);
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Loan.DOM_CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY.CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY == CurrentOwnershipEntity);
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentOwnershipEntity = null;
        ViewData["CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.DOM_CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITies select n).ToList(), "CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY", "CURRENT_OWNERSHIP_ENTITY");
    }

    // responsible party
    if ((Request.Form["RESPONSIBLE_PARTY"] != null) && Request.Form["RESPONSIBLE_PARTY"] != "")
    {
        ResponsibleParty = Request.Form["RESPONSIBLE_PARTY"];
        ViewData["RESPONSIBLE_PARTY"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.ACTION_PLANs select n).ToList(), "RESPONSIBLE_PARTY", "RESPONSIBLE_PARTY", ResponsibleParty);
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.RESPONSIBLE_PARTY == ResponsibleParty);
    }
    else
    {
        ResponsibleParty = null;
        ViewData["RESPONSIBLE_PARTY"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.ACTION_PLANs select n).ToList(), "RESPONSIBLE_PARTY", "RESPONSIBLE_PARTY");
    }

    // completed
    if ((Request.Form["COMPLETED"] != null) && Request.Form["COMPLETED"] != "")
    {
        Completed = System.Convert.ToBoolean(Request.Form["COMPLETED"]);
        ViewData["COMPLETED"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.ACTION_PLANs where (n.COMPLETED != null) select new { n.COMPLETED}).Distinct().ToList(), "COMPLETED", "COMPLETED", Completed);
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.COMPLETED == Completed);
    }
    else
    {
        Completed = System.Convert.ToBoolean(null);
        ViewData["COMPLETED"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.ACTION_PLANs where (n.COMPLETED != null) select new { n.COMPLETED }).Distinct().ToList(), "COMPLETED", "COMPLETED");
    }

    // target date
    if ((Request.Form["TARGET_DATE"] != null) && Request.Form["TARGET_DATE"] != "")
    {
        TargetDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["TARGET_DATE"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        ViewData["TARGET_DATE"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.ACTION_PLANs select n).ToList(), "TARGET_DATE", "TARGET_DATE", TargetDate);
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.TARGET_DATE == Convert.ToDateTime(TargetDate));
    }
    else
    {
        TargetDate = "";
        ViewData["TARGET_DATE"] = new SelectList((from n in _db.ACTION_PLANs select n).ToList(), "TARGET_DATE", "TARGET_DATE");
    }
```

Comment: So you are binding your ddl to a list of all people? Is there any reason that you cannot filter the datasource you are binding to, so that it only includes people with action plans? You would do this either in the code layer or at the data access layer. This should be trivial to implement - perhaps a code sample would help to identify just where you are getting stuck?

Comment: David is correct...we would be able to help better if we knew how you were trying to populate your DDL.  Just to piggyback on what David said, you can filter results of a collection using LINQ, you can just make another call to your DB and bind the results to your DDL, etc.  It just depends on how you're trying to feed data into the DDL.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Sql question basically you want your dropdown to show the result of this request :

Pseudo code :

```
Select Person.* from Person Inner Join ActionPlan on Person.PersonnId = ActionPlan.PersonId
```

The inner join make your query return only rows from the table person that have a record in the ActionPlan table.

Comment: yes that sql example is what i want to display, but i am unsure as to where or how i can have my dropdownlist follow that... so far i have

<td><%=Html.DropDownList("FORMER_BORROWER", "All")%></td>

Answer (score 0):

Doing some quick googling on Html.DropDownList seems to point to this being ASP.Net MVC - is that correct?

If you are using MVC I'm surprised that you have made is as far as displaying database data on screen without having an idea where you can filter that data. Did you autogenerate everything so far perhaps?

I haven't used MVC very much but just put together a quick and dirty example in Visual Studio. You should see a two folders, one called Views and one called Controllers.

In the Views folder should be a view file which is where the markup you provided lives.

In the Controllers folder there should be a controller file for your view, which will be a class with content looking something like this:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class YourController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult YourView()
        {
            ViewData["FORMER_BORROWER"] = new SelectList(db.Borrowers.ToList, "BorrowerID, "Name");               

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The bit of code which binds the DropDownList control is the line:
    ViewData["FORMER_BORROWER"] = ...

Now in that SelectList the first parameter is simply an IEnumerable (in my case accessing the database) so you can use LINQ to filter that object.

Below is a trivial example where the IEnumerable I provide is create in code, but the code the is accessing you database can be used in a similar way. Not how I use a join to give only the values needed.

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Swimming", Value = "1" }); 
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Cycling", Value = "2", Selected = true }); 
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Running", Value = "3" });         

List<ExerciseType> et = new List<ExerciseType>();
    et.Add(new ExerciseType{Id="1"});
    et.Add(new ExerciseType{Id="2"});

// the line below uses LINQ to filter out the item with text of "Swimming"            
var filteredList = from x in items
                    join y in et on x.Value equals y.Id
                    where x.Text != "Swimming"
                    select x;


ViewData["Testing"] = new SelectList(filteredList, "Value", "Text");
```

The code above will now only show one item in the DDL - the Cycling item due to the join and the where.

Taking your controller code, you would end up with something like the code below (only focusing on one half of the FORMER_BORROWER if/else branch)

```
FormerBorrower = Request.Form["FORMER_BORROWER"];            
ViewData["FORMER_BORROWER"] = new SelectList((
    from n in _db.Loans
    join x in _db.ActionPlans on n.BorrowerId equals x.BorrowerId
    where (n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME != null) 
    select new { n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME, FORMER_BORROWER_NAMEID = n.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME }).Distinct().ToList(), 
    "FORMER_BORROWER_NAMEID", 
    "FORMER_BORROWER_NAME", FormerBorrower);

    predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Loan.FORMER_BORROWER_NAME == FormerBorrower);
```

One comment on the answer above is that while this will work, I would personally look at tweaking the design, creating some sort of service for the controller to call, abstracting away some of this data access logic. Ideally you should now have your ObjectContext up in your controller layer but down in the service layer, giving a more focussed controller that is not trying to control the view at the same time as accessing the data layer.

Comment: i provided code above. did u want to see the whole controller or just that, the reason i am stuck is because i cannot hard code the dropdownlist to specific values because it is dynamic to the data. 
thanks for your help so far